# logical (jshint friendly) equivalent of this assignment in a while loop

Tags: javascript, refactoring, jshint

```
  dispose: function() {
    var disposer;
    while (disposer = this._disposers.shift()) { // expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.
      disposer();
    }
  },
```

`jshint` isn't happy that `disposer` is assigned in the `while` loop.

is there any way to maintain this logic and make it `jshint` friendly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I missed something...

```
dispose: function() {
    var disposer = this._disposers.shift();
    while (disposer) {
        disposer();
        disposer = this._disposers.shift();
    }
},
```

You may also want to buff up your conditional:

```
while (typeof disposer === 'function') {
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DPNYq/

Comment: `var this._disposers.shift();` makes no sense :-P

Answer (score 6):

You can fix it simply by using `()`.

```
dispose: function () {
    var disposer;
    while ((disposer = this._disposers.shift())) {
        disposer();
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as simplicity goes this definitely wins.

Comment: in the unlikely event that _disposers ever contained something that wasn't a function you would get a TypeError error.

Answer (score 1):

```
dispose: function() {
  var disposer;
  while (typeof (disposer = this._disposers.shift()) === 'function') {
    disposer();
  }
},
```